# Is there a shorter way to define an object structure with variable keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

```
var adddata = {};
adddata[ group ] = {};
adddata[ group ].type = type;
adddata[ group ].items = {};
adddata[ group ].items[ id ] = value;
$.extend( data, adddata );
```

Do i really need to define `adddata` this long way? If `group` and `id` are fixed strings, it's pretty short

```
$.extend( data, { group1:{ type: type, items:{ id1: value } } } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript only supports literal keys within object literals. You can only make the code a little shorter:

```
var adddata = {};
adddata[group] = { type: type, items: {} };
adddata[group].items[id] = value;
$.extend(data, adddata);
```

Comment: yes of course, that looks better. do you know, how i can delete the key `id` from `adddata`. I tried `adddata[group].items[id] = null;` It's _null_ but `...items[id]` is still abvailable.

Comment: @Alex, use the [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/delete) operator: `delete adddata[group].items[id];`